# Two color hard background doesn't look good

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Maybe I am alone with this issue but I want to ask for help anyway. I started to create a two color background and found a bug.
First this is my code:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0000ff;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff0000 50%, #0000ff 50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title here</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        Content here ... Test 1 2 3 4
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see a screenshot of my local page here:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

The gradient works almost fine, but as you can see there is a 1 pixel height with 100% width light red colored line, which shouldn't be there. How can i remove it? I tried already to set color stops to it or set it to 0%, but it didn't change the result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be setting background to `html` also, set it only for `body`. Also you'll need to add `margin: 0` for removing scrollbars:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff0000 50%, #0000ff 50%);
}
```

```html
Content here ... Test 1 2 3 4
```

Also you can remove `width: 100%` because `body` is `block` by default, and move to `vh` (this will eliminate need to set `100%` to `html`):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff0000 50%, #0000ff 50%);
}
```

```html
Content here ... Test 1 2 3 4
```